# Arduino will not read three successive packets in the serial connection

Tags: serial, python, bytes

I have written a small program to send serial commands from Python to the Arduino Micro.  This is my code for both:

Python

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM5', 9600)

ser.write(b'0')
ser.write(b'1')
# ser.write(b'2')

print('done')
```

Arduino

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{

  while (!Serial.available()){}
  Serial.println(Serial.read()-48); 

}
```

If I keep the `ser.write(b'2')` line in the Python code commented out, the code executes nearly instantly, and I am able to see both transmissions in the serial monitor. If I uncomment it, the Python code takes about 5-7 seconds to execute, and none of the data comes through the serial monitor.

I've tried different baud rates but that hasn't helped. I've also tried sending an integer rather than `b'#'`, and the same thing happens, no data is transmitted if I have all three serial commands active.

What is happening in my code? Is the serial buffer overloaded by the three successive writes and the buffer ends up flushing?

Comment: are you sure it is not a problem every second run and not dependent on the `write` lines?

Comment: Hi Juraj, I'm not sure what you mean, can you clarify?

Comment: It runs reliably with 2 writes.  It fails every time with 3 writes.

Comment: what if you send '0' and '2'  or '1' and '2'.   Same issue?

Comment: You don't overload your input buffer, but your output buffer

Comment: Chad, I will try that, but I think the last time I did, I just got 0's at the output.
Chrisl, Are you sure?  This serial test is part of a much larger program which sends hundreds of serial commands every second, and I suspect the output buffer would have gotten saturated very quickly, but I haven't run into that problem, I dont think....

Comment: Are you testing with the code above, or with your larger program? That makes a difference. The above code will most likely fill the output buffer fast, because there is nothing, that would slow the loop down. If you have a larger program, it may slow down the loop enough (depending on the program). so that the ATMega has enough time to send out the data and empty the buffer.

Comment: This may be an issue with python. A full RX buffer on the Arduino does not do anything to the python program, since there is no flow control with Arduino UART. If the input buffer is full, data will simply lost. No blocking of the sender.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see a loop that is able to overflow any buffer. The python script just finishes after sending 3 bytes. The arduino sketch will only print if anything anything has been received. Also, from my experience an atmega running at 8Mhz is absolutely fast enough to poll for incoming bytes that are transmitted at a baudrate of 9600...

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake. Read it falsely. But still I would assume, that the error lies more with the python side, assuming that the OP really tests with the code above and not with the larger code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your code works but you substract 48 from what you received. 

Which if python sends a `char` with values: `'0'` `'1'` `'2'` it will result in the serially outputted values of `NUL` `SOH` `STX` which are invisible.

If python transmits the raw byte value (aka `0x00` `0x01` `0x02`) this would result in `0x00 - 48 = undefined behaviour` with a underflow (same goes for `0x01` and `0x02`)